# How do I run multiple GNUplot commands using popen() in C?

Tags: c, gnuplot, popen

this is my first question here!
I'm trying to create a dynamic plot that updates periodically using GNUplot through C. Here is the sample code for what I'm trying to do

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *data,*flsrt;
    FILE *gnupipe;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    data=fopen("dat2.dat","w");
    flsrt=fopen("t1.txt","r");
    fprintf(data,"%d\t%d\n",i,j);
    gnupipe=popen("gnuplot -persistent","w");
    char *GNUC1[]= {"plot 'dat.dat' using 2:1 with lines","reread","replot"};
    fprintf(gnupipe,"%s\n",GNUC1[0]);
    while(k<5000)
    {
        fprintf(data,"%d\t%d\n",++i,++j);
        //fprintf(gnupipe,"%s\n",GNUC4);
        fprintf(gnupipe,"%s\n",GNUC1[1]);
        fprintf(gnupipe,"%s\n",GNUC1[2]);
        k++;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

However, the pipeline seems to mess up after a few iterations, and I keep getting this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ardZC.png)
I have no idea how to go about fixing this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you forgot to post the actual error. If you could edit that in, we would have an easier time helping you out.

Comment: Was this retyped and miscopied?  `FILE data, flsrt;` shouldn't compile, it should be `FILE *`.  Also you are writing data to `dat2.dat` but plotting the contents of `dat.dat` instead.   Once those are fixed, you probably need to do some `fflush`ing.

Comment: Thanks, I did in fact, forget to link the image, and I also corrected the typo. As for **'fflush'ing** , could you please elaborate?

Comment: stdio functions like `fprintf` buffer their data and don't necessarily write it to its destination until later.  To force it to be written out, use `fflush` (see its documentation).  You need to `fflush(data)` after writing to `data` to ensure the new data actually makes it there, and `fflush(gnupipe)` after sending the commands to ensure that gnuplot sees them before the next iteration.

Comment: You also have a race condition, in that there is no guarantee that gnuplot finishes plotting one version of the file before you update it again.  That's more difficult to fix because I don't know if there is any way to "query" gnuplot to find out if it's done.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! the fflushing seems to have worked. As for the race condition, could adding a pause statement with adequate delay work?

Comment: It would reduce the risk but not eliminate it.  You have no way of knowing how long a delay is "adequate".

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there a different, more efficient way of both updating the data file and plotting in real-time using C?

Comment: data file missing